# iOS object or delegate between two controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue, weak-references

Evening, my question is full about theory.

I understood reading from **Apple developer documentation** that is better to use the **Delegates Pattern** to keep track of some object attributes. In this way we can access the delegate without access to the object. (I really didn't get the reason of this choice)

I also understood that is better to define: `protocolDelegate: class`
and when we are declaring the delegate inside the class it's better to use the `weak` word to prevent some "kind of problem cycle". (??)

So, while I was playing a bit with code, I've discovered that you can't pass a `weak delegate` between two `view controllers`, because of course, when you change the controller, the `weak delegate` is going to be deleted because is a `weak` thing (or at least this is what I understood).

So, I have to choose between 2 options:

- make the delegate "strong" deleting the `weak` key.
- or pass the object in the segue and keep the delegate as `weak`.

I have a lot of confusion, can you clear my mind? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cycle you're referring to is called a *retain cycle*.

Let's use a concrete example to clear this up: say you've got a `UIViewController` which has a `UITableView`. The view controller has a strong reference to the table view. The view controller now wants to act as the delegate to the table view.

Now, if the table view would have a *strong* reference to its delegate, we would have the following situation: the view controller has a strong reference to the table view, and the table view in turn would have a strong reference back to the view controller. Thus neither can ever get deallocated.

To break this cycle, references to delegates are usually *weak*. This allows the retain count of the view controller to drop to 0 eventually, which can in turn release the table view.

Your classes that want to use delegates should also follow this pattern and use *weak* references to their delegates. You should thus pass the required references via your segue.

Comment: so you are saying that I should pass the object in the segue?

Comment: I'm not sure what "object" refers to in this case. You didn't describe your apps design in this regard in detail, so it's hard to give you advice. But I recommend you make your `delegate` property `weak`, since that's a convention everyone is following (reasons are explained in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I will concentrate on the first part of your question, since the previous answers have covered the rest pretty well.

Consider the following situation: you have a class that handles some kind of network connection - it sends a request to a server and gets a response. Outside of this class there is a viewController that has a button that triggers the request and a view which presents the response to the user.

Basically, the network handling class should be able to get some message from the viewController (button pressed) on one hand and pass the viewController the response on the other. So there should be bidirectional communication between the two classes. While the passing of the buttonPressed message to the network handling class is pretty obvious, the reverse part (passing the response) is a bit more tricky, because the network handling class should not be aware of who created it and who calls it (good OO practices and memory leaks prevention).

That's the point where the delegate pattern comes in. It allows an object to pass data to whoever is interested in it without knowing anything about the recipient. The class that passes the response only knows some 'delegate' and not another class. In addition you can take out the network handling class as is and put it in another project. Because it isn't supposed to know any other class from its original project, only some 'delegate', it can be put into another project without any modifications.

I hope it can help you to get the reason of the choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think pass the object with segue, `Segues` are a very important part of using Storyboards in Xcode.  We can go over the different types of `segues`another time, but this one shows you how to use the “Show” segue, as well as how to `pass data between` the two view controllers to customize the second one with whatever custom data is required.

You can easily use segues example; Under below you can send `currentstring` to `destinationViewController` inside `sentstring`  , also `ShowSegue` is your segue `identifier`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowSegue" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? OtherViewController {
            destinationVC.sentstring = currentstring
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already knew this part, my question was about segue and delegates, but really thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Navigation between viewcontrollers maintain `stack` of viewcontrollers.

For example `aVC` is firstviewcontroller then top of stack will be `aVC`,

now when you push or show another viewcontroller say `bVC` then now top of statck is `bVC`. So stack looks like,

`aVC -> bVC(top)`

now you push another `cVC` then,

`aVC -> bVC -> cVC(top)`.

So top of stack is always visible to user.

at current situation, aVC and bVC and cVC are not deallocate. they are in memory. But if you pop or dismiss cVC, then it will deallocate from memory and now your top of stack looka like,

`aVC -> bVC(top)`.

So viewcontrollers live in stack till they are not popped or removed. So, they are strog reference by default.

`Segue` is nothing but you can say that they are graphical representation of push or pop operation.

another thing is that delegate should be `weak` that because it can create retain cycle if they are strong.

you can called delegate as `representative` in general sense.

Now, if you are using segue, send your object in `prepareForsegue` and it will manage everything else.